# My code only works properly in 'step into' and not normally

Tags: c#

Basically i want my code to generate two random numbers and then what they equal. It works how it should when i go into step into but not normally and i can't for the life of me figure out why! when i run it normally the two numbers are always the same, however when i step into the program they are different. I want them both to be random. I'm using visual studio 2015 if that helps. 
Thank you in advance!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DiceRoll DR = new DiceRoll();
        DR.SecondRolledDice();
    }
}  

public int RolledDice()
    {
        Random numberGenerator;
        numberGenerator = new Random();
        int firstdiceroll = numberGenerator.Next(1, 7);

        return firstdiceroll;
    }        

    public void SecondRolledDice()
    {
        Random SecondnumberGenerator;
        SecondnumberGenerator = new Random();
        int seconddiceroll = SecondnumberGenerator.Next(1, 7);

        DiceRoll DR = new DiceRoll();
        var diceroll = DR.RolledDice();

        string NumberName;
        string NumberNameTwo;
        string sum;
        string[] SecondNumberNames;
        SecondNumberNames = new string[12] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "seven", "eight", "Nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"};

        NumberName = SecondNumberNames[seconddiceroll - 1];
        NumberNameTwo = SecondNumberNames[diceroll - 1];
        sum = SecondNumberNames[(diceroll + seconddiceroll) - 1];

        Console.WriteLine("{0} Plus {1} Equals {2} ", NumberName, NumberNameTwo, sum);         
    }
```

Comment: did you step all the way through your code right to the end?

Comment: Initialize numberGenerator in the constructor of DiceRoll

Comment: Why is `SecondRolledDice()` creating a new instance of `DiceRoll`?

Comment: you program runs fast.  The random numbers are generated using the system time.  So you get te same number when running without debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> The Random() constructor uses the system clock to provide a seed
> value. This is the most common way of instantiating the random number
> generator.
>
> If the same seed is used for separate Random objects, they will
> generate the same series of random numbers.

Also, from the *Avoiding multiple instantiations* section:

> Initializing two random number generators in a tight loop or in rapid
> succession creates two random number generators that can produce
> identical sequences of random numbers. In most cases, this is not the
> developer's intent and can lead to performance issues, because
> instantiating and initializing a random number generator is a
> relatively expensive process.
>
> Both to improve performance and to avoid
> inadvertently creating separate random number generators that generate
> identical numeric sequences, we recommend that you create one Random
> object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of creating
> new Random objects to generate one random number.

You need to instantiate random once, then call `Next` method for both dice.

Comment: Thank you so much thats worked an absolute treat! i fully understand it now as well, beautiful, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RolledDice()` method is recreating the `Random` object each time it's called, which is what is causing the same numbers to be generated.

Simply declare your `Random numberGenerator = new Random();` once as a global variable (maybe, for good practice create it on the main method instantiation) and then reuse it.